# Magento - Partially overriding indexAction of OnePage controller

Tags: magento, overriding, action

I need to partially override the indexAction of OnePage controller. I'm trying to add in a way to get direct to the review step on returning to onepage checkout - all other steps are completed at this point, it's just that Magento behaviour is to start again! It will mean changes to the onestep.phtml as well, but I haven't got the far yet!

My controller override is working fine. I can add a new action on the controller, say reviewStepAction, but if I have this as a simple override for testing, the standard onepage checkout is not displayed. I get blank page with just the standard sidebar:

```
public function reviewStepAction() {
  parent::indexAction();
}
```

I've also tried copying and modify indexAction to my action function, but still not getting the onepage checkout to display. The final part of indexAction is:

```
    $this->getOnepage()->initCheckout();
    $this->loadLayout();
    $this->_initLayoutMessages('customer/session');
    $this->getLayout()->getBlock('head')->setTitle($this->__('Checkout'));
    $this->renderLayout();
```

So I'm guessing it's not working because the URL is ../checkout/onpegage/reviewstep so it's trying to load a "reviewstep" layout and not finding one. How can I force reviewStepAction to finish off by loading the usual /checkout/onepage layout? I tred using `Mage::getSingleton('checkout/opnepage)` but that just crashed.

I can't just redirect to checkout/onepage at the end of my action because that would invoke the standard indexAction and I need to insert something between `initCheckout` and `renderLayout`.

Thanks.

Comment: Anyone? Let me sum up: I've added an action to the Onepage controller and at the end of the action I want to render the normal onepage checkout page. Really easy to say, but seemingly impossible to do!

Answer (score 0):

The following works:

```
public function reviewStepAction()
{
    $this->loadLayout(array('default','checkout_onepage_index'));
    $this->getOnepage()->initCheckout();
    ...additional code...
    $this->_initLayoutMessages('customer/session');
    $this->getLayout()->getBlock('head')->setTitle($this->__('Checkout'));
    $this->renderLayout();
}
```

Only point to note is that the body class is set to `checkout-onepage-reviewstep` instead of the usual `checkout-onepage-index`.